# AWS Lambda VPC on Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

When creating an AWS Lambda Function with terraform 0.9.3, I'm failing to make it join my selected VPC.

This is how my function looks like:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
   s3_bucket        = "${var.s3_bucket}"
   s3_key           = "${var.s3_key}"
   function_name    = "${var.function_name}"
   role             = "${var.role_arn}"
   handler          = "${var.handler}"

   runtime          = "${var.runtime}"
   timeout          = "30"
   memory_size      = 256
   publish          = true

   vpc_config {
       subnet_ids = ["${var.subnet_ids}"]
       security_group_ids = ["${var.security_group_ids}"]
   }
 }
```

The policy I'm using for the role is

```
 data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda-policy_policy_document" {
       statement {
            effect = "Allow"
            actions = [
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
        ]
        resources = ["*"]
     }
 }
```

The resources are created just fine, if I try to add the VPC and the subnets via the AWS console it all works out.

Update (creation plan):

```
module.******.aws_lambda_function.lambda_function
arn:                                 "<computed>"
environment.#:                       "1"
environment.0.variables.%:           "1"
environment.0.variables.environment: "******"
function_name:                       "******"
handler:                             "******"
last_modified:                       "<computed>"
memory_size:                         "256"
publish:                             "true"
qualified_arn:                       "<computed>"
role:                                "******"
runtime:                             "******"
s3_bucket:                           "******"
s3_key:                              "******"
source_code_hash:                    "<computed>"
timeout:                             "30"
version:                             "<computed>"
vpc_config.#:                        "1"
vpc_config.0.vpc_id:                 "<computed>"
```

Though, if I run terraform plan again, the VPC config is always changed.

```
vpc_config.#: "0" => "1" (forces new resource)
```

Comment: Can you show the plan output when you don't have the Lambda function there?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR just updated with the creation plan

Comment: That looks wrong to me. I've just planned one of my own Lambda functions that happens to be inside a VPC and I see extra lines on the plan for the security group ids and subnet ids that your plan doesn't show. Something like: `vpc_config.0.subnet_ids.1220732747:           "subnet-12345678"`. Have you checked your subnet IDs and security group IDs are correctly being passed in?

Comment: For reference the module I'm using is public (https://github.com/tomelliff/s3-web-service-proxy/blob/master/terraform/modules/s3-web-service-proxy/lambda.tf) but your configuration for your module looks fine compared to that so I'd guess it's down to how you are calling the module.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR you were right I was missing a mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a mapping missing to the lambda module. After fixing it this how the plan should have looked like for the VPC configuration:

```
vpc_config.#:                              "1"
vpc_config.0.security_group_ids.#:         "1"
vpc_config.0.security_group_ids.571116572: "******"
vpc_config.0.subnet_ids.#:                 "3"
vpc_config.0.subnet_ids.1396457994:        "****"
vpc_config.0.subnet_ids.1722519307:        "****"
vpc_config.0.subnet_ids.830820656:         "****"
vpc_config.0.vpc_id:                       "<computed>"
```

Comment: how do you implement this @joaofs?  In the tf code?

Answer (score 7):

I think the value of `subnet_ids` is like this: `"subnet-xxxxx,subnet-yyyyy,subnet-zzzzz"` and it take it as single subnet instead of list. You can fix this problem like this:

```
vpc_config {
  subnet_ids = ["${split(",", var.subnet_ids)}"]
  security_group_ids = ["${var.security_group_ids}"]
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I solved it by changing the definition of the var.subnet_ids to be a list.
```
    variable "subnet_ids" {
      default = ["subnet-0xxxc", "subnet-0xxxa", "subnet-0xxx1", "subnet-0xxxc"]
    }
```

Then in my vpc_config just use: 
```
subnet_ids = "${var.subnet_ids}"
```

Comment: which terraform version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Terraform V0.12.9

Comment: you can try it with terraform v0.11.x, for v0.12.x, I am working on my code

Comment: ```  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = split(",", var.subnets)
    security_group_ids = split(",", var.security_groups)
  }
```
This worked for me.